# Impute values of a vector using Cosine similarity in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, imputation

### The Scenario

I have a Dataset whose last column has NaN values in it, which need to be imputed using only Vector Cosine & Pearson Correlation; after which the data will be further taken for Clustering.

### The Problem

It is mandatory for my case to use **VECTOR COSINE** and **PEARSON CORELATION**.

Here's a chunk of how my dataset is
**post_df1** which is taken from csv using pandas

```
       uid     iid       rat
1    303.0   785.0  3.000000
2    291.0  1042.0  4.000000
3    234.0  1184.0  2.000000
4    102.0   768.0  2.000000
254  944.0   170.0  5.000000
255  944.0   171.0  5.000000
256  944.0   172.0       NaN
257  944.0   173.0       NaN
258  944.0   174.0       NaN
```

Which is now taken into a Vector (Just to make it easy, suggestions required) using this command

```
vect_1 = post_df1.iloc[:, 2].values
```

Yet with `sklearn.preprocessing`'s Class called `Imputer` are having `Mean, Median & Most frequent` methods available, but won't work according to my Scenario.

### Questions

1. Is there any other Package than [SurPRISE](https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise) (by Nicholas Hug), for Vector Cosine & Pearson mehtod
2. Is it possible to pass a function / method in sklearn for cosine & pearson?
3. Any other method / way out?

Answer (score 1):

Cosine silirality and Pearson correlation are only parameters in the imputation method, not imputation method. There are various methods of imputation, such as KNN, MICE, SVD and Matrix Factorization. For example, it is possible to use cosine silirality as a parameter of one KNN of the imputation method, but its implementation itself could not be found. `fancyimpute` package may be helpful as a package with a near implementation. The following is the link. GitHub - hammerlab / fancyimpute: Multivariate imputation and matrix completion algorithms implemented in Python https://github.com/hammerlab/fancyimpute/

Comment: I didn't quite get this line _"only parameters in the imputation method, not imputation method"_. I'll try fancyimpute though.

Comment: I am sorry I can not answer easy to understand. For example, in hierarchical clustering, I think that taking a distance as an argument, similarly, taking cosine similarity and Pearson correlation as an argument of the method of imputation, it is not itself a method.